# C# Reflection on Nested Properties of a Class

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, reflection, properties

I wanted to know how can I get the Value of Property in C#, but this property is of another Type.

```
public class Customer
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Lastname {get; set;}
   public CustomerAddress Address {get; set;}
}
```

So I'm able to get the property values of Name and LastName but I quite don't get how to get the value of CustomerAddress.City.

This is what I have until now.

```
public object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string property)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property))
   return new object { };

   PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(property);
   return propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

Then is use this method in a LINQ statement.

```
var cells = (from m in model
                         select new
                         {
                             i = GetPropertyValue(m, key),
                             cell = from c in columns
                                select reflection.GetPropertyValue(m, c)
                     }).ToArray();
```

So I get no value for the CustomerAddress.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

**** UPDATE ****

Here how I managed to do it.

```
public object GetNestedPropertyValue(object obj, string property)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property)) 
                return string.Empty;

            var propertyNames = property.Split('.');

            foreach (var p in propertyNames)
            {
                if (obj == null)
                    return string.Empty;

                Type type = obj.GetType();
                PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty(p);
                if (info == null)
                    return string.Empty;

                obj = info.GetValue(obj, null);

            }

            return obj;
        }
```

Comment: How about setting the value of a nested property ? (Same as this one, but for info.SetValue...) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, if you want to get the value of `CustomerAddress.City`, you will never get it.  `CustomerAddress` is the type, not the property name.  You want to get `Address.City`.

That said, your `GetPropertyValue` is not set up to do what you want.

Try splitting the name by the dots:

`var propertyNames = property.split('.');`

Now, you have a list of the property names `{"Address", "City"}`

Then, you can loop through these property names, one by one, calling `GetPropertyValue` recursively.

That should do it :)

Answer (score 0):

@Michael -> the inverted part;-)

```
public static void SetNestedPropertyValue(object obj, string property,object value)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("property");

            var propertyNames = property.Split('.');

            foreach (var p in propertyNames)
            {

                Type type = obj.GetType();
                PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty(p);
                if (info != null)
                {
                    info.SetValue(obj, value);
                    return;
                }

            }

            throw new KeyNotFoundException("Nested property could not be found.");
        }
```

Comment: This is completely useless, it does not even have a simple Typeconversion. Also it will not create a new instance of the parent-objects. There will be a nullreference on the second iteration in the foreach. This does not work at all, only for strings and only if it is NOT a complex type.